# Add my own button next to "Screen options" and "Help" in the admin

Tags: admin, admin-menu

I'd like to add my own button link next to these two. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Any reason you can't just hook into contextual help (i.e. the *Help* tab)?

Answer (score 4):

The HTML

```
echo '<div id="screen-meta-links">';
echo ' <div id="contextual-help-link-wrap" class="hide-if-no-js screen-meta-toggle">';
echo '  <a href="#" id="your-own-button" class="show-settings">Text for your button</a>';
echo ' </div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<br style="clera:both" />';

echo '<div id="your-button-content" class="your-button-hide">';
// your content goes here
echo '</div>';
```

And you need some custom JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

$( '.your-button-hide' ).each(
  function(e){
    $( this ).hide();
  }
);

$( '#your-own-button' ).click(
  function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    $( '#your-button-content' ).toggle();

    var hasclass = $( '#your-own-button' ).hasClass( 'screen-meta-active' );
    if( hasclass ){
      $( '#your-own-button' ).removeClass( 'screen-meta-active' );
    } else {
      $( '#your-own-button' ).addClass( 'screen-meta-active' );
    }
  }
);

});
```

The HTML part adds the button, the JavaScript adds the functionality.

The complete code could look like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_backendpage', 10, 0 );

function register_backendpage() {
  $pagehook = add_management_page(
    'Your backend page',
    'Your backend page',
    'manage_options',
    'a-menu-slug-of-your-choice',
    'backendpage_callback',
    false,
    'bottom'
  );

  add_action( 'load-' . $pagehook, 'enqueue_button_script', 10, 0 );
}

function backendpage_callback() {

    // output your button here, see code above

    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    /*
     * the rest of your page content
     */
}

function enqueue_button_script() {
    // the js above
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-button-script', ... );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why this question was dismissed so quickly. It's actually a valid question, and would be really useful to be able to add a button up there, or even edit the content of each screen option.

I know this is an old question, but...

If you want it to just add a button up there that would link somewhere else. You could just add some jQuery to add the button.

```
jQuery("#screen-meta-links").append('<div id="contextual-help-link-wrap" class="hide-if-no-js screen-meta-toggle" style=""><a href="link.html" id="contextual-help-link" class="show-settings">My New Button</a></div>');
```

Now if you actually want that button to work in the same way as the other buttons, you would need to dig into the admin files.

The file you are looking for is:

wordpress\wp-admin\includes\screen.php

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple and exact clean solution for adding your own such button:

```
class TmMS_Controller extends TmMS {

    //...

    public function init() {
        //...            
        add_action('admin_footer', array(&$this, 'admin_footer'));
        // ...
    }



    public function admin_footer() {
    if (empty($_GET) OR (isset($_GET['post_type']) AND $_GET['post_type'] == 'post')) {
        if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] == admin_url('edit.php')) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function() {
                    jQuery('#screen-meta-links').append('<div class="hide-if-no-js screen-meta-toggle" id="mail-subscriber-options-link-wrap" style=""><a aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="screen-options-wrap" class="show-settings" id="mail-subscriber-settings-link" href="#mail-subscriber-options-wrap">Newsplus</a></div>');
                    var mail_subscriber_options_wrap = jQuery('#mail_subscriber_options').html();
                    jQuery('#mail_subscriber_options').remove();
                    jQuery('#screen-meta').append(mail_subscriber_options_wrap);
                });

            </script>
            <?php
            $this->draw_prepared_posts_content();
        }
    }
}

    public function draw_prepared_posts_content() {
        $data = array();

        echo $this->draw_html('admin/prepared_posts_content', $data);
    }

    // ...

}

$tm_ms_controller = new TmMS_Controller();
add_action('init', array(&$tm_ms_controller, 'init'), 1, 999);
```

Add css instructions somewhere:

```
#mail-subscriber-options-link-wrap {
float: right;
height: 23px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 0 6px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

#mail-subscriber-options-link-wrap {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

/* screen options and help tabs */
#mail-subscriber-options-link-wrap {
    border-right: 1px solid #d1e5ee;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1e5ee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1e5ee;
    background: #eff8ff;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#def1ff), to(#eff8ff));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #def1ff, #eff8ff);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #def1ff, #eff8ff);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #def1ff, #eff8ff);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #def1ff, #eff8ff);
}

#mail-subscriber-options-posts{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Screens:
[image: Result of script working]
[image: code architecture]
[image: function to generate html]

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Not without some JavaScript.

> Will it be possible?

Those two tabs will be converted into a menu in the admin bar in WP 3.3. Check out the beta.